# how to finish an activity from a handler?

Tags: android, handler, android-alertdialog, activity-finish

i am calling Alert dialog froma handler.Alert dialog has 2 buttons "play Again" and "Exit".
i have written the code to restart the activity in "play again" button. but i dont know how to finish the application when i click on exit button. i cant call finish () from my handler.given below is my code.please anybody help me...

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
            builder.setMessage("Game Over !!!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Play Again",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                                    //thread.start();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent ( _context , DroidzActivity.class );                                    
                                    _context.startActivity ( intent ); 
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Exit",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                                    dialog.cancel(); 

                                }
                            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
           }




            };
```

Comment: nobody knows the solution????? :(

Answer (score 1):

In case your above code is in your activity which you would like to finish, try the following code:

```
YourActivity.this.finish();
```

**Edit**:
I propose not destroying the current activity but starting in the following way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent ( _context , DroidzActivity.class );    
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
_context.startActivity ( intent );
```

And handle "play Again" action in `onNewIntent()` method. You will need to override it in your activity.

For more reference please check: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

and

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)

Comment: this alert dialog code is not in the main activity class..it is in a separate class..so i could not use this

Comment: Instead of destroying the activity and starting it again, I propose the use of `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and `onNewIntent()`. I updated my answer.

Comment: i just want to exit the application when i click on "exit" button...no need to restart the activity

Comment: `_context` is your activity which would you like to finish ? Where is initialized ?